# Как узнать разницу между временем Android

Tags: java, android, время

Есть два время, допустим 17:25:28 и 20:49:12.

Разница должна составить 03:33:44.

Каким образом можно узнать разницу между данными временами?

Comment: привести в секунды, вычесть, привести обратно. Самый просто вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разницу в секундах можно так получить:

```
DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date1 = df.parse("17:25:28");
Date date2 = df.parse("20:49:12");
//делим на тысячу, так как разность в миллисекундах
long diff = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / 1000;
```

Далее:

```
long hours = diff / 3600;
long minutes = (diff - (3600 * hours)) / 60;
long seconds = (diff - (3600 * hours)) - minutes * 60;
System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

> 3:23:44

Comment: Для вычисления минут и секунд есть записи покороче: `long minutes = (diff % 3600) / 60;`, `long seconds = diff % 60;`.

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться [таким](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7663966/7129209) методом:

```
public static String getDurationBreakdown(long millis) {
    if(millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duration must be greater than zero!");
    }

    long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millis);
    millis -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis);
    millis -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
    millis -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
    sb.append(days);
    sb.append(" Days ");
    sb.append(hours);
    sb.append(" Hours ");
    sb.append(minutes);
    sb.append(" Minutes ");
    sb.append(seconds);
    sb.append(" Seconds");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Пример использования:

```
long start = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
Thread.sleep(5000);
long end = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println(getDurationBreakdown(end - start));
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
0 Days 0 Hours 0 Minutes 5 Seconds
```